Как изменить репозиторий в Source Control?
Захотелось подключить VSCode к Github.
В итоге VSCode выбрал как источник весь комп и в Source Control висит постоянное обновление:

При этом файлов, очевидно, очень много:

При вводе git status вылетают экстеншены VSCode и папки, которые лежат на компе:



Собственно, вопросы:

Что вообще делать?
Можно ли как-то сменить репозиторий в Source Control и как, если да?

Работаю непосредственно в папке проекта, которая лежит на компе в папке @_Dev

Просто удалить скрытую папку .git из домашней папки, вы скорее всего случайно туда добавили. При необходимости инициализируйте git в папке проекта.
